# Find the flow for the following dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following dynamical system:

$\dot{x_1}= -x_2 + (x_1(1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2))$ , $
\dot{x_2}= x_1 + (x_2(1-(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2))$, 
$\dot{x_3}= \epsilon x_3$ .
 I am required to work out the flow for this system. I have switched it to cylindrical coordinates obtaining $\dot{r}=r(1-r^4)$ , $\dot{\theta}=1$, $\dot{z}=\epsilon{z}$.

I assume in order to work out $r$ I must use partial fractions, but I'm not really sure how to proceed with this, as surely it gets a bit awkward. Have I made a mistake somewhere? Is this the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796491/poincare-first-return-map-stability-and-bifurcations, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794825/determining-bifurcations and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794735/characteristic-exponents-multipliers.

Comment: Thanks, but these questions are asking something different to mine. I am asking how we initially determine the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Have to write something otherwise it doesn't let me post the comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40246/discussion-on-answer-by-snowman-find-the-flow-for-the-following-dynamical-system).